# removeView() on the child's parent

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, user-interface

I'm getting

```
E/AndroidRuntime(855): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() 
on the child's parent first.
```

The code I'm running, the error happens on linearLayout.addView(view);

```
view = getFieldControl(field);
linearLayout.addView(view);
```

Where getFieldControl looks like this(simplified):

```
private android.view.View getFieldControl(ControlTemplate control)
{
    View view =null;    
    view = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    ((EditText) view).setHint(control.getName());
    ((EditText) view).setText(control.getValue()); 

return view;
}
```

I don't understand what the views parent could be, where should I remove it from?

Comment: where your R.id.edit_message exists?

Comment: In the linearlayout that is set as the contentView of the activity.

Comment: if you set as contentView then what is the need of adding it to the layout again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your EditText programmatically as below

```
private android.widget.EditText getFieldControl(ControlTemplate control)
{
    EditText edittext = new EditText(this);
    edittext.setHint(control.getName());
    edittext.setText(control.getValue()); 
    return edittext;
}
```

**Note :** If the `EditText` is in XML which is set as Content View modify the code as below by removing the line `linearLayout.addView(view);` because already the `EditText` is added in the layout through XML.

```
EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);;
getFieldControl(edittext, field);

private void getFieldControl(EditText edittext, ControlTemplate control)
{
    edittext.setHint(control.getName());
    edittext.setText(control.getValue()); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you call the getFieldControl(field) method more than once, you are trying to get the EditText of R.id.edit_message from XML and adding that more than once to the layout. Hence it's giving this error. Make sure that you add this EditText only once to any of the layouts.

Comment: Is there no way to go around this? I really need to create several EditTexts from the same template in the xml.

Comment: Then, you have to create a new edit text dynamically and add those to your layout. Don't get them from XML file. Otherwise, create a seperate layout with that edit text only and inflate that at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Your `EditText` `R.id.edit_message` must be in an `.xml` file or say `layout`, that `layout` is the parent of the `EditText`.

Create a dynamic `EditText` instead.